# Why this event is not fired on fiddle?

Tags: jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhj2m/1/) is the code! I really don't know why `addTrack` is not recognized :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="addTrack(this);return false" value=" Add ">

function addTrack(param) {
    alert("ciao");
}
```

Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: addTrack is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the script insertion mode to `no wrap (head)` instead of `onLoad` and it will work as expected.

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhj2m/2/).

Comment: And the reason why the original didn't work is because `addTrack` was not in scope as it was defined within `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

[see working eg](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhj2m/3/)
It wasn't defined, because the script was wrapped in the `ready` eventHandler; it was declared in a different scope(not the public one) and it wasn't visible

Answer (score 1):

Moving the function declaration from the jQuery `.load()` handler to the outer scope (`head`) [solves the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/Yhj2m/4/). Guess the function was only available within the scope of `$.load()`.